# Can I place a variable inside of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, google-colaboratory

I want to put an variable from a dictionary called Theo_Skutar_contact and put it inside of the value of another dictionary called all_contact_dictionary. This is my code and please help me figure this out as this is a project for my dad's job. You type in a name and it searches for the contact. In this case I used Theodore Skutar.

```
all_contact_dictionary = {
    "First Last": First_Last_contact,
}

First_Last_contact = {
    "First Name": "First",
    "Nickname": "Nick",
    "Last Name": "Last",
    "Company": "WorkingInc",
}

while True:
  name_input = input("Type first and last name here with capitals. Don't type nicknames.  ")

  if name_input in all_contact_dictionary:
    print(all_contact_dictionary[name_input])
  else:
    print("Not found. Try again.")
```

In the first dictionary is where I want to link it in the second value.

I tried doing ", i tried no ", i tried ', and nothing worked.

Comment: You can nest dictionaries in dictionaries in Python, so you can place the value of a variable inside the dictionary. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Yes, binaryescape.

Comment: create a new dictionary for every input, then place it into the main dictionary with the correct key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

Although I would suggest learning about Classes and Objects going forwards from here for this.

```py
theo_skutar_contact = {
    "First Name": "Theodore",
    "Nickname": "Theo",
    "Last Name": "Skutar",
    "Company": "SomeCompany",
}

dave_murray_contact = {
    "First Name": "David",
    "Nickname": "Dave",
    "Last Name": "Murray",
    "Company": "Iron Maiden",
}

all_contact_dictionary = {
    "Theodore Skutar": theo_skutar,
    "David Murray": dave_murray_contact,
}

while True:
  name_input = input("Type first and last name here with capitals. Don't type nicknames.  ")

  if name_input in all_contact_dictionary:
    print(all_contact_dictionary[name_input])
  else:
    print("Not found. Try again.")

>> {'First Name': 'Theodore', 'Nickname': 'Theo', 'Last Name': 'Skutar', 'Company': 'SomeCompany'}
```

An example of using a dataclass

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Contact:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    nickname: str 
    company: str

theo_skutar = Contact(first_name = "Theodore", last_name = "Skutar", nickname= "Theo", company = "CompanyA")
dave_murray = Contact(first_name = "David", last_name = "Murray", nickname= "Dave", company = "Iron Maiden")


all_contact_dictionary = {
    "Theodore Skutar": theo_skutar,
    "David Murray": dave_murray,
}


while True:
  name_input = input("Type first and last name here with capitals. Don't type nicknames.  ")

  if name_input in all_contact_dictionary:
    print(all_contact_dictionary[name_input])
    print(all_contact_dictionary[name_input].nickname)
  else:
    print("Not found. Try again.")

>>> Contact(first_name='Theodore', last_name='Skutar', nickname='Theo', company='CompanyA')
>>> Theo
```

Comment: The thing is, I am going to have multiple contacts. Will it work and how?

Comment: If you want to continue using dictionaries then you'd need a dictionary per person. I'd personally be using a Class instead of a dictionary for each contact.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: can you make it 2 contacts so I know how it works better please @SimonT ? I appreciate your help, I am sorry for also wasting your time, but I am an beginner to coding.